# Python on Windows: How to bring to foreground a window specified by thread ID using pywinauto?

Tags: python, windows, automation, pywinauto

Using the pywinauto library with Python 3.10.x on Windows, I would like to focus (bring to the foreground) a certain window for which I only know the associated thread ID or, if that is not enough, I could know also the process ID, that is, the IDs returned from: `win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)`. How can I achieve that?

I think I have to use the `set_focus()` method, but don't know on which object to call it. I want to achieve something similar to the following, where I know only the process ID:

```
app = Application().connect(process=pid)
app.top_window().set_focus()
```

Comment: How can you focus by PID if you don't know the PID of the app? Windows don't have PIDs. Windows are tied to a thread and a thread is tied to a process...

Comment: Sorry, I have modified the question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: GetWindowThreadProcessId returns a tuple with the process and thread id of a window. You can't focus a process, only a window and you already have that (hwnd).

Comment: I have modified the question one more time. Though I think what I need is not possible.

Comment: did you tried the 2 lines of code you written above?